# Programatically open barcode scanner in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am very new in ionic.I am making qr code generator and bar code scanner app.I already made that and display that scanned data but I want display that data for some second and on scanner automatically.Code below.

> qr.html

```
<button ion-button full icon-left (click)="createCode()"><ion-icon name="barcode"></ion-icon>Code Generator</button>
<button ion-button full icon-left (click)="scanCode()"><ion-icon name="qr-scanner"></ion-icon>Scanner</button>

<ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
    <ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Value: {{ createdCode }}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

 <ion-card *ngIf="scannedCode">
 <ion-card-content>
  <p>Value : {{ scannedCode }}</p>
 </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
```

> qr.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-qr',
templateUrl: 'qr.html',
})
export class QrPage {

qrData=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('response'));
createdCode=null;
scannedCode=null;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad QrPage');
}

createCode() {
this.createdCode=this.qrData;
}

scanCode() {
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData=>{
  this.scannedCode=barcodeData.text; //save scanned code
})
}
}
```

after click scan button one time. After scan code display it for some second and automatically open scanner.this process continue till I click back button of my device.How I do that? Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to read. Do you want to open the scanner programmatically some time after you scanned a barcode? If that's the case just use `setTimeout` in your `scanCode` method to call `scanCode` again: `setTimeout(() => { this.scanCode(); }, 3000);`

Comment: @Phonolog I want when I open this page and click scan button just one.after scan that code only 5second and open scanner again. If I setTimeout that scanner close completely.I want that button triggered after some second programatically. how I do that?

Comment: Then change your `scanCode() {
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData=>{
  this.scannedCode=barcodeData.text; //save scanned code
  setTimeout(() => { this.scanCode(); }, 5000);
})
}`

Comment: not woking...scanner code stop and display code for some second